# Finding total number of words in .txt document

Tags: python

```
find = open("words.txt")

def noE():    
    for line in find:
        if line.find("e") == -1:
            word = line.strip()
            print word,

noE()
```

The above code searches the .txt file for all words that do not contain the letter "e" and then prints them. I would like to then be able to get a count of the total number of words under this *if* conditional.  I looked into the python docs and found Count() but the import wasn't working for me (assuming I did something wrong). Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `count = 0` outside the loop, `count += 1` inside that `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be more pythonic, and useful if you want to use the words for something else:

```
find = open("find.txt")

noes = [line.strip() for line in find if line.find("e")== -1]

print(noes)
print(len(noes))
```

Comment: I like this version as well but it is a little above my current knowledge base. I am following the Think Python book for now...Also, this prints the total number of characters in each word on each line in the .txt.

I am trying to find the total numbers of words.

Comment: Sorry Zah, this did exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Being a beginner I didn't recognize the single line format. Do you know of a good resource that explains this style?

Comment: Here you have a nice introduction: http://www.udacity.com/view#Course/cs212/CourseRev/apr2012/Unit/71001/Nugget/72001

Comment: Great! I will check that out. Thank you for posting a link for me!

Answer (score 3):

Just add a counter variable inside of your `for` loop.

Also, don't use `line.find('e')`. Use the `in` keyword instead:

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as handle:
    total = 0

    for line in handle:
        if 'e' not in line:
            total += 1
            word = line.strip()

            print word,
```

Comment: This is a pretty clean version of what I posted but doesn't find the total number of words in the .txt that don't contain the letter "e"...Thus the counter variable but I am having troubles understanding how that works.